# Django - How to use AJAX within a form

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use AJAX for the first time as we have a Django project but a required feature is for one form to behave more like a react app or SPA so I'm trying to use AJAX to add that functionality. I have the following template for the page. It has a form to let the user select from a dropdown what their highest education is and should have a modal appear to let the user input a qualification at a time to be added to the database and displayed on the table. The issue is when the user fills out the modal and clicks submit it seem's to perform just a normal GET request as can be seen below rather than the API request to create qualifications from the modal. AJAX seemingly isn't intercepting the request.

GET REQUEST

```
 "GET /applications/personal-details/prior-attainment/4/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=s54x6U2BczYThuoYKTryBZwUzdPDuaxmzzubamRRz2Lw4qX1ztjGnAP1XcryPHXP&subject=Maths&qualification_name=Nat+5&date_achieved=2024-02-13&level_grade=A HTTP/1.1" 200 7974
```

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

`{% block content %}
<div class="container mt-5">
    <h2>Prior Attainment and Qualifications</h2>
    <form id="priorAttainmentForm" method="post" action="{% url 'prior_attainment_view' application_id %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="highestQualification">Highest Qualification Level</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="highestQualification" name="highest_qualification_level">
                {% for value, label in form.highest_qualification_level.field.choices %}
                <option value="{{ value }}" {% if form.highest_qualification_level.value == value %} selected {% endif %}>{{ label }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
        <hr>
    <h3>Qualifications</h3>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success mb-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#qualificationModal">Add Qualification</button>
    <div id="qualificationTable">
        <!-- Table gets populated by JavaScript -->
    </div>
    <hr>

    <button type="submit" name="action" value="save_and_continue" class="btn btn-primary">Continue</button>
        <button type="submit" name="action" value="save_and_return" class="btn btn-secondary">Save and Return</button>
    </form>


    <!-- Qualification Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="qualificationModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="qualificationModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form id="qualificationForm">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="qualificationModalLabel">Add Qualification</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <!-- CSRF Token -->
                        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{ csrf_token }}">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="qualificationSubject">Subject</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qualificationSubject" name="subject" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="qualificationName">Qualification Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qualificationName" name="qualification_name" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="qualificationDateAchieved">Date Achieved</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="qualificationDateAchieved" name="date_achieved" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="qualificationLevelGrade">Level/Grade</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qualificationLevelGrade" name="level_grade" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Qualification</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  {% endblock %}
`

{% block extra_js %}
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    const loadQualifications = () => {
        // AJAX call to load qualifications
        $.get("{% url 'qualifications_list_api' %}", function(data) {
            let listHtml = '';
            data.forEach(qualification => {
                listHtml += `<div>${qualification.subject} - ${qualification.qualification_name} - ${qualification.date_achieved} - ${qualification.level_grade}</div>`;
            });
            $('#qualificationsList').html(listHtml);
        });
    };

    $('#qualificationForm').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = $(this).serialize();

        $.post("{% url 'qualification_create_api' %}", formData, function(response) {
            if(response.success) {
                $('#qualificationModal').modal('hide');
                loadQualifications();
                return false
            } else {
                alert('Error saving qualification');
                return false
            }
        }).fail(function() {
            alert('Failed to save qualification');
            return false
        });
    });

    loadQualifications();
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Within the base.html I also have the basic structure below. (The script imports are a mess this is being built as a really quick demo for supervisors as a POC)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static i18n %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{% block title %}My Django Project{% endblock title %}</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}"> -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    {% block extrahead %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    </header>

    <main role="main" class="container">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock content %}
    </main>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    {% block extrajs %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

URLS for adding Qualification in URLS.py

```
path('/qualifications/add/', views.add_qualification, name='add_qualification'),
    path('/qualifications/<int:qualification_id>/edit/', views.edit_qualification, name='edit_qualification'),
    path('/qualifications/<int:qualification_id>/delete/', views.delete_qualification, name='delete_qualification'),
```

Views for the URLS

```
def add_qualification(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QualificationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            qualification = form.save()
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'success', 'id': qualification.id})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'error', 'errors': form.errors})

def edit_qualification(request, qualification_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        qualification = get_object_or_404(Qualification, pk=qualification_id)
        form = QualificationForm(request.POST, instance=qualification)
        if form.is_valid():
            qualification = form.save()
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'success', 'id': qualification.id})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'error', 'errors': form.errors})

def delete_qualification(request, qualification_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        qualification = get_object_or_404(Qualification, pk=qualification_id)
        qualification.delete()
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'})
```

I've tried following multiple guides on setting up AJAX and also had some AI tools check over the code and all say it should seemingly work but the AJAX just does not seem to work and now been stuck on this for a couple of days. I'm expecting it to essentially just create the qualification using the route, to then close the modal and display the all qualification's. I do recognise it would have been much simpler to use React and I wish we did but for other reasons Django had to be used for the POC.

Edit: Further details,

The template contains 2 forms, the second one in the modal is what needs to perform the AJAX request. At current moment it sends a get request that can be seen above rather than an AJAX request. As far as I can tell its as if AJAX is not running in the first place to intercept the request and perform its own.

Comment: Only the qualificationForm will be ajax. Not priorAttainmentForm. Because you haven't bind to that from.

Comment: Yeah that’s the goal for the qualification form to be able to send Ajax queries and create qualifications etc

Comment: `AJAX seemingly isn't intercepting the request.` Does requests reach server? What you see in browser console when ajax is profome?

Comment: What are these  `action="{% url 'prior_attainment_view' application_id %}">`  and  `$.post("{% url 'qualification_create_api' %}`? Shouldn't they be like `app_name:url_name`?

Comment: They essentially function the same way just using url way goes by djangos url naming scheme to map to urls rather than using app_name:url_name but they have the same result I believe

Comment: Provide more info/code.